# Email validation in Javascript - how to add extra conditions

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I need to validate email addresses, in addition to the basic structure, I need also

- email address can not start or end with special character
- email address can not have double special character
  edited
  special characters are

  ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~

Character . ( period, dot or fullstop) provided that it is not the first or last character and it will not come one after the other.

So that's what I have so far that's just validates the basic structure

```
function emailIsValid (email) {
  return /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email)
}
```

How do I add the above 2 conditions to it? Thank you

Edited
**valid addresses**

```
jen@gmail.com
jen@company.gov.ca
jen.doe@gmail.com
jen123@gmail.com
```

**invalid**

```
@jen@gmail
jen@gmail
.jen@gmail.com
jen.@gmail.com
&jen@gmail.com
jen@gmail.com.
```

Comment: What is a special character?

Comment: @jabaa edited, thank you!

Comment: Your validation doesn't find all valid addresses: https://regexr.com/5voh7 According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address `" "@example.org` is a valid email address. If you don't support the official RFC you should describe the supported pattern.

Comment: If you are asking for a regex solution, then you should include sample inputs and expected results (pass/fail). See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: @JDB done! added some examples

Comment: For what it's worth, the `+` symbol is commonly used by GMail users: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308648?hl=en

Comment: Also, my email address has a period in it. Can I not use your service? I've been rejected from other websites (including e-commerce) because of this.

Comment: @JDB, it's mostly for corporate emails so it's ok not to validate plus

Comment: @sarsnake - My corporate email address has a period in it. Every email address at my company has a period in it. Do you want to lose business over a naive regex? However... you know your use-case. Just food for thought.

Comment: @jdb oh period like jen.doe@gmail.com is OK (see above)

Comment: Why do you want to disallow valid email addresses? Is this just an academic task or does it really have a use-case?

Comment: @jabaa, it's a requirement.

Comment: Just to make sure. You want to block `john__smith@ibm.com`?

Comment: @jabaa, yes! and if they realize that, then I will fix it later. I was specifically asked no consecutive special characters so

Comment: In my opinion this question is a bad question and I downvote it because it's asking about email validation but you want to disallow valid email addresses and allow invalid email addresses. It's unrelated to email validation. You're just trying to find a strange pattern. Neither the basic structure nor the added requirements can be called email validation.

Comment: @jabaa - At the end of the day a programmer has got to do what they've been asked to do (or quit). If sarsnake has been given specific requirements then, good or bad, those are the requirements that the programmer must deliver (or quit). I've been asked to do lots of things I've thought better of, but if I quit every time I was handed poorly considered requirements then I would have starved to death a decade ago.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica I'm not saying that the requirement is good or bad. I'm just saying that the title and description of the question are misleading and therefore not useful. AFAIK Stack Overflow is a Q&A platform with the goal to help future users to find help. Future users will find this question and maybe even copy the regex but it's unrelated to email validation. I would remove my downvote if the term "email validation" were removed or replaced with "email-like validation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options.

1. **Don't bother validating email addresses.**

This is probably the best choice. Ultimately, the only way to know if an email address is legit is to send a piece of unique data to that address and instruct the user to share that unique data with you, proving they have access to the mailbox (and thus that the mailbox exists, and thus that its address is legitimate).

I don't expect you to follow this advice.

2. **Add extra conditions *after* the regex.**

You know, you don't *have* to do the entire job with a single regex. Doing so will actually be harder.

Since you've provided the list, here's an attempt at strategy 2:

```js
const FORBIDDEN_TERMINAL_CHARACTERS = [
  `!`,
  `#`,
  `$`,
  `%`,
  `&`,
  `'`,
  `*`,
  `+`,
  `-`,
  `/`,
  `=`,
  `?`,
  `^`,
  `_`,
  '`', // single quotes around tick
  `{`,
  `|`,
  `}`,
  `~`
]

function emailIsValid (email) {
  let syntaxGood = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email)
  if(!syntaxGood) return false // skip loop if we've already failed
  
  for( let badChar of FORBIDDEN_TERMINAL_CHARACTERS ) {
    if(email.startsWith(badChar) || email.endsWith(badChar)) {
      return false // terminate early
    }
  }
  
  return true
}
```

This is probably your second-best option.

3. **Cram all of this extra logic into a single regular expression.**

This is a bad idea. Regular expressions are sometimes jokingly described as "write-only": the only person who can understand a regex is the person who wrote it, and even then *only while they are actively creating it*. Once it's in the rear-view mirror, they forget all the hairy contextual details, and it becomes opaque even to them. Good luck to future maintainers trying to modify this regex if, e.g. you want to add or remove one character to the list of forbidden ones. If you don't have a very robust set of automated test cases for this function, every future edit will probably break something.

<strike>The specifics of how to encode that regex will depend on the specific list of forbidden characters. So, if you want anyone on SO to attempt that code, you will have to provide the complete list.</strike>

Comment: I like choice 2. I agree with your 1) but my boss wants client side validation so...